# PerspectiveTransform and Crop Rectangle in Android using openCV

Tags: android, opencv

I receive an image from Android camera using `CvCameraViewListener2`
My program detect a yellow rectangle plate.
The problem is after I know the 4 points which are the corner of rectangle, I want to crop the rectangle and shown in the `JavaCameraView`

Here is my program's screenshot when it detect a rectangle.

[image]

First, I apply `perspectiveTransform` to transform an image into correct perspective. But the result is very bad like

[image]

I have no idea how to correctly do this.
The following is my code.

```
private Mat getTransform(Mat inputFrame, List<Point> corners) {
    Mat outputFrame = inputFrame.clone();
    //compute width of new image
    double widthA = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(corners.get(3).x - corners.get(2).x, 2) + Math.pow(corners.get(3).y - corners.get(2).y, 2));
    double widthB = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(corners.get(1).x - corners.get(0).x, 2) + Math.pow(corners.get(1).y - corners.get(0).y, 2));
    double maxWidth = max(widthA, widthB);

    // compute heigh of new image
    double heightA = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(corners.get(1).x - corners.get(3).x, 2) + Math.pow(corners.get(1).y - corners.get(3).y, 2));
    double heightB = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(corners.get(0).x - corners.get(2).x, 2) + Math.pow(corners.get(0).y - corners.get(2).y, 2));
    double maxHeight = max(heightA, heightB);

    Log.d(MAINTAG, "Width: " + maxWidth + ", Height: " + maxHeight);

    List<Point> output = new ArrayList<>();
    output.add(new Point(0, 0));
    output.add(new Point(0, maxHeight));
    output.add(new Point(maxWidth, maxHeight));
    output.add(new Point(maxWidth, 0));

    Mat inputMat = Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(corners);
    Mat outputMat = Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(output);

    Mat outputTransform = Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(inputMat, outputMat);

    Imgproc.warpPerspective(inputFrame, outputFrame, outputTransform, new Size(outputMat.width(), outputMat.height()), Imgproc.INTER_LINEAR);

    return outputFrame;
```

The `corners` is arranged as topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight
After correct the perspective, the screen gets freeze!!!

Second, I want to crop the rectangle after I correct its perspective and show in `JavaCameraView`. How do I do that?

Thank you for all solutions and suggestions.

Comment: To crop the final image, you need to create a cv::Rect with top-left xorner coordinates x,y and the rect width and height (!!!after!!! transformation. you might want to apply warpPerspective to the original Rect)